# Simple multiplation program GUI gone wrong. Java

Tags: java, user-interface

so I attempted to make a simple 'Area Finder' Program.  It works text based, however when I add a GUI it errors out, and I have no idea what is causing it.  Sorry if my spelling is off, I am not the greatest of spellers.

**Code**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class AF implements ActionListener {

    double length;
    double width;
    double answer;

    JTextField twidth = null;
    JTextField tlength = null;

    void AFWindow() {

        JFrame AFwindow = new JFrame();
        JPanel pan2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        AFwindow.setVisible(true);
        AFwindow.setSize(250, 150);
        AFwindow.setResizable(false);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        AFwindow.add(pan2);
        pan2.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 5;
        JTextField tlength = new JTextField();
        tlength.setText("    Length    ");
        pan2.add(tlength, c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        JTextField twidth = new JTextField();
        twidth.setText("     Width     ");
        pan2.add(twidth, c);

        JButton Find = new JButton("Ok");

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = -5;
        pan2.add(Find);
        Find.addActionListener(this);
        Find.setActionCommand("ok");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
            try {
                this.length = Double.parseDouble(tlength.getText());
                this.width = Double.parseDouble(twidth.getText());

            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println("There was an issue!");
            }
        }
    }

    int area = (int) (length * width);

    public void answer() {
        JFrame answer = new JFrame();
        answer.setVisible(true);
        answer.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        JPanel pan2 = new JPanel();
        JLabel howanswer = new JLabel("Your answer is" + area
                + "We got this by multiplaying the length and width");
        pan2.add(howanswer);
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at AF.actionPerformed(AF.java:53)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could please add the stack trace and relevant portions of code directly in your question?

Answer (score 2):

In your class, you have:

```
JTextField tlength = null;
JTextField twidth = null;
```

And then in the constructor you have:

```
JTextField tlength = new JTextField();
tlength.setText("    Length    ");
pan2.add(tlength, c);
...
JTextField twidth = new JTextField();
twidth.setText("     Width     ");
pan2.add(twidth, c);
```

These `tlength` and `twidth` that you declare and add to your JPanel are local variables within the scope of that constructor only. The `actionPerformed` method is instead referencing the *class*'s instance variables `tlength` and `twidth`, which are still null because they were never instantiated. So when you try to call `tlength.getText()`, you will throw a NullPointerException.

To fix, change the line `JTextField tlength = new JTextField();` in your constructor to be `tlength = new JTextField();`. Do the same for the `JTextField twidth = ...` line.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a `NullPointerException` because you are calling `tlength.getText()` when `tlength` is `null`.  You'll run into the same problem with `twidth`.

To solve this problem, instantiate these variables before your action is fired.

Specifically, make the following changes.

```
JTextField tlength = new JTextField();
JTextField twidth = new JTextField();
// Update the lines above to the following.
this.tlength = new JTextField();
this.twidth = new JTextField();
```

Roddy gives a good explanation as to why these particular changes are relevant.

Comment: Alright, you help me a lot, if its not too much to ask, why now, does the answer JFrame not pop up?

Comment: @TimothyO'Connell I have no idea, sorry.  I know next to nothing about `java.awt`.  You're better off posting another question with more information.